# .net core + vue + coalescevue

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core

Im trying to use this package

https://github.com/IntelliTect/Coalesce.Vue.Template

Under the heading **Creating a new Coalesce project using the template** it says:

```
Run dotnet coalesce to trigger Coalesce's code generation.
```

However, when I try to do this I get the message

```
dotnet : No executable found matching command "dotnet-coalesce"
```

I cant find anything further in the documentation that indicates that Im missing anything, so any help would be appreciated

Comment: did you execute it on CMD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should Running `dotnet coalesce` in the **web project’s** root directory .

Suppose i add a new EF entity like( i use newproject as project name just for testing) :

```
namespace newproject.Data.Models
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset? BirthDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Use `Run dotnet ef migrations` add Init (Init can be any name) in the data project to create an initial database migration :

```
PS D:\nanyu\newproject\newproject.Data> dotnet ef migrations add Init
```

Next run`dotnet coalesce` in the web project’s root directory :

```
PS D:\nanyu\newproject\newproject.Data> cd D:\nanyu\newproject\newproject.Web
PS D:\nanyu\newproject\newproject.Web> dotnet coalesce
```

Coalesce’s code generation will start generation:
[image]
You will find related generated files in web application .